# SQL Server : convert historical data to Temporal Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have SQL Server 2016. For many years we have our own history. Now I want to convert historical data to a new format, and use the CustomAudit tables as a history table with already available historical data.

For the beginning there will be a small example, then the question

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[client]
(
     idclient int identity(1,1) primary key, 
     clientData nvarchar (400)
) ON [PRIMARY] 

INSERT [dbo].[client] ( clientData ) values ('some-12221')
INSERT [dbo].[client] ( clientData ) values ('some-22111')

alter table [client] 
add 
    StartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START  DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(), 
    EndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'), 
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartTime,EndTime) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomAydit_client]
(
    idclient int,
    dEditDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()), 
    clientData nvarchar (400)
) ON [PRIMARY] 

alter table [CustomAydit_client] 
add 
    StartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START  DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(), 
    EndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END DEFAULT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'), 
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartTime,EndTime)

INSERT [dbo].[CustomAydit_client] (idclient, dEditDate, clientData) 
VALUES (1, (CAST(N'2016-05-06 10:08:11.923' AS DateTime)), 'some-1')

INSERT [dbo].[CustomAydit_client] (idclient, dEditDate, clientData) 
VALUES (1, (CAST(N'2016-02-11 10:08:11.923' AS DateTime)), 'some-211')

INSERT [dbo].[CustomAydit_client] (idclient, dEditDate, clientData) 
VALUES (2, (CAST(N'2016-12-06 10:08:11.923' AS DateTime)), 'some-1')

INSERT [dbo].[CustomAydit_client] (idclient, dEditDate, clientData) 
VALUES (1, (CAST(N'2015-05-19 10:08:11.923' AS DateTime)), 'some-1')

INSERT [dbo].[CustomAydit_client] (idclient, dEditDate, clientData) 
VALUES (2, (CAST(N'2016-05-06 10:08:11.923' AS DateTime)), 'some-211')

INSERT [dbo].[CustomAydit_client] (idclient, dEditDate, clientData)
VALUES (1, (CAST(N'2016-05-26 10:08:11.923' AS DateTime)), 'some-1')

INSERT [dbo].[CustomAydit_client] (idclient, dEditDate, clientData) 
VALUES (2, (CAST(N'2016-05-06 10:08:11.923' AS DateTime)), 'some33-1')

INSERT [dbo].[CustomAydit_client] (idclient, dEditDate, clientData) 
VALUES (1, (CAST(N'2016-05-06 10:08:11.923' AS DateTime)), 'some3-1')

INSERT [dbo].[CustomAydit_client] (idclient, dEditDate,clientData) 
VALUES (2, (CAST(N'2016-11-16 10:08:11.923' AS DateTime)), 'some-1')

INSERT [dbo].[CustomAydit_client] (idclient, dEditDate, clientData) 
VALUES (1, (CAST(N'2016-02-17 10:08:11.923' AS DateTime)), 'some-1')
```

I need StartTime for row AND  for row.

For customer 1, I want to take row 2 data of field DeditDate

Update this data row  1 field EndTime

And the last line, the client should not have EndTime, this  ok 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY idclient ORDER BY dEditDate) AS tempid,
    idclient,
    dEditDate,
    StartTime, EndTime
FROM
    [dbo].[CustomAydit_client]
ORDER BY
    idclient, dEditDate
```

Comment: You did a great job posting the table definition and sample data. But it is not very clear to me what you want as output.

Comment: In Temporal Tables for the row your need StartTime and EndTime. I don't how to do  EndTime correct. Use my data

Comment: I need somesing like that https://1drv.ms/i/s!ApEvwFL7i3nmkvlgTivat9If6J_vdQ

Comment: Not sure what that image is supposed to show me. Your output looks like the same thing as the data entered. Or are you trying to make the end date be start date value of the "next" row??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lead` function to get a value from the next row as endtime.

```
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idclient ORDER BY dEditDate) AS tempid,
    idclient,
    dEditDate,
    StartTime,
    lead(dEditDate) over(PARTITION BY idclient ORDER BY dEditDate) as EndTime
from [dbo].[CustomAydit_client]
order by idclient, dEditDate
```

Comment: Do you have any experience about the performance of `lead` in case of many many rows (beyond 100 mio)?

Comment: Thanks you can help me a lot

Comment: @GoAnatol, did you get the answer for you question? I need exactly the same thing